# System of Units Based on Energy and Time

Tags: physical-constants, absolute-units

Is it possible to have a system of units  in which  Time and Energy  as the fundamental quantities and others as derived quantities. Also using only pi,e , avagadro number and planck's constant

Comment: It is called geometrized with only length fundamental, but you can replace it with time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system

Comment: Planck’s constant has the dimensions of energy times time. If you set it to 1, energy and time are no longer independent dimensions.

Comment: G.Smith Thanks. Got new idea. I can treat "h" as the unit of a new quantity "X-energy carrier" -similar to electric charge .   dQ/dt--> current  ,  dX/dt -->energy. then it would be consistent with E=hf . Have you heard about role of avagadro constant in particle physics.